# Data is not written into file for no reason

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

In my function, I want to open the newly created file and write my data into it, following [these instructions](https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/articles/how-access-tizen-file-system). Here is my code:

```
function writeDataToFile(newFile) {
    try {
        console.log("[Matin] writeDataToFile started...");
        if(newFile != null) {
            newFile.openStream('a', onOpenStream, function(error) {
                console.log("[Matin] Could not create the file.");
                console(error);
            }, "UTF-8");

            function onOpenStream(fs) {
                console.log("[Matin] New file is opened.");
                fs.write("Hello ---------- Data Goes Here ----------");
                fs.write(JSON.stringify(dataToFile));
                console.log("[Matin] this is the data to be written>>>\n" + JSON.stringify(dataToFile));
                fs.close();
                dataToFile = null;
                newFile = null;
                console.log("[Matin] Data is written into the file, and temporal variables are set to null.");
            };
        } else {
            console.log("[Matin] no file here to write into!...");
        }
        console.log("[Matin] writeDataToFile ended!!!");
    } catch (exception) {
        console.log("[Matin] [Exception] " + exception.message);
    }
}
```

and this is the logs I am getting from executing the function. Everything looks fine:

```
js/managers/exportManager.js (295) :[Matin] writeDataToFile started...
js/managers/exportManager.js (314) :[Matin] writeDataToFile ended!!!
js/managers/exportManager.js (303) :[Matin] New file is opened.
js/managers/exportManager.js (305) :[Matin] this is the data to be written>>>
[{"steps":null,"heartrate":null,"accelX":"-0.9709117078781128","accelY":"3.4513116836547852","accelZ":"8.347122440338135",...]
js/managers/exportManager.js (309) :[Matin] Data is written into the file, and temporal variables are set to null.
```

But the problem is, when I look at the file, nothing is written into it! The file has no data in it. Not even the line `Hello ---------- Data Goes Here ----------`.
What could possibly be the reason? Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**
The function works perfectly fine and the files are correctly saved. However, **a restart** is needed on the watch so you can read the files. Otherwise, it's going to show you empty files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your specific case right here, nor do I know Tizen, but I hopefully can help with this anecdote of mine.

File permissions: I had an issue before where I was developing on Linux based system and the user who created the file was not the same as the user the program was being executed as so the program didn't have proper write permissions. It only had read permissions. Therefore it appeared that everything was working correctly, but in reality it was failing to write because the program didn't have write permissions to the file.

Comment: I don't think that's the case here, because the program is able to create the file, but cannot write into it.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631643/creating-and-writing-into-a-file-in-gear-s/30644950#30644950

Comment: What could possibly be the problem? I have already given the application the `write` permission.